# Iterate from A..Z in a Smarty loop

Tags: php, smarty

What is the best way of iterating through a sequence of letters A..Z in a Smarty loop for a section of a template?

I'm using Smarty 2, not 3, so I presume you have to use `{foreach}` or `{section}` and not `{for}`

I'm sure this is one of those questions where the answer is obvious and simple and I will end up slapping myself when I see what it is!

**Update:** Ideally I would like a template only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a template only solution. Here you go.

```
{assign var=arr value='A'|range:'Z'}

{foreach from=$arr item=item}
{$item}
{/foreach}
```

Output

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Comment: Excellent!! I'll test and get back later

Answer (score 2):

Server side (PHP)

```
$arr = range("A","Z");
$smarty->assign('myArray', $arr);
```

Template

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$myArray item=letter}
    <li>{$letter}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: I was hoping to have a template only solution - but it looks like this is the only way to go. :(